# How to read this and meaning

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context, traditional-characters, old-chinese

Just want to know how to read and meaning of this.[image]

Comment: It is an imitation of [符](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%AC%A6%E5%92%92/3589697), all nonsense

Comment: It's a "Doodle" trying to depict / imitate some ancient Chinese alchemical formula for casting spells / "magic", (much like the Pentagram of ancient Western magic), with some common Chinese words strewn around to give it "authenticity" It is shaped like a Pagoda, presumably with various "entities" inhabiting various levels.

Comment: I feel that this is something similar to a talisman that a child made out of words.